# React - getting error export Multiple components for use as an NPM package

Tags: reactjs, npm, import, components, export

button.js

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ButtonElements extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button type={this.props.btnType} onClick={this.props.click}>
        {this.props.btnText}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

export default ButtonElements;
```

text.js

```js
import React from "react";

const TextElement = props => <h2>{props.label}</h2>;

export default TextElement;
```

index.js

```js
import ButtonElements from "./component/button/button";
import TextElement from "./component/text/text";

export { ButtonElements, TextElement };
```

---

webpack.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: ["./src/index.js"],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("lib"),
    filename: "index.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs2"
}
```

My project:

```js
import ButtonElements from "npm-package";
import TextElement from "npm-package";

<ButtonElements iClass="faSort" btnText="T"></ButtonElements>
<TextElement label="T"></TextElement>
```

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports

Comment: Did you try `import { ButtonElements } from "npm-package";`?

Comment: It's working.
```
import { ButtonElements } from "npm-package"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`import { ButtonElements } from "npm-package";`